# What's the workflow to bulk delete e-mails from within Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I'm getting the out-of-storage space error for Gmail:

[How does Gmail's "out of storage space" work?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86582/how-does-gmails-out-of-storage-space-work)

Since I'm [obviously doing it wrong](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/101080/cannot-bulk-delete-from-gmail), what's the correct way to delete all e-mails within a label **without creating a filter** or deleting the label itself?

Comment: I don't think you're doing it wrong. I think there's some issue between your network and Google's.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Search for the messages you want to delete
   example: `label:mylabel`
2. Click the checkbox at the top to select all of the conversations on the page
3. You'll get a message similar to:

   > All 100 conversations on this page are selected. Select all 75432 conversations

   The latter portion is a clickable link. Click it.
4. Now all your messages matching the search are "checked"
5. Click "Delete"

It may take a few minutes to move them all to *Trash*.

If you get an error, you're probably simply trying to do too many at once for your local browser, network, and/or server to handle. (It shouldn't happen, but apparently it does for you.) Try breaking your search up into smaller, but manageable, chunks. There are several [advanced search operators](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190) you can use. You might try one of the time-based operators, so you can do something like this:

Search for all the messages with your label that are older than a year:

```
label:mylabel older_than:1y
```

Then follow the other steps above.

Comment: what happens if, in those few minutes, the browser is closed or the connection terminated?

Comment: I don't know. I'd expect that the work is being done server side, and so it wouldn't matter, but only a Google engineer could answer definitively. Worst case is you'll need to try again, maybe with a smaller chunk.