# To what extent are filters dependent upon the browser?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, google-apps-email, inbox-by-gmail

Context:

I've [pared down some of my larger gmail labels by deleting old, labeled e-mails](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/101127/whats-the-workflow-to-bulk-delete-e-mails-from-within-gmail).  Because I've exceeded my quota, I'm now going through old mail by performing a search for `has:nouserlabels`.  From those results I'm visually looking for e-mail lists and then filtering those lists, then deleting them.

Conceivably I could just delete the query results for `has:nouserlabels`.  Probably there wouldn't be an adverse effects.  For now, however, I'll just try to label old e-mails.

Question:

When the browser is closed or the connection interrupted **before** the filter has done *everything*, but after the filter is created (which the gmail web interface will report with `your filter has been created`, will the filter continue to run and operate on old e-mails?

I ask because bulk deletes [seem to stall](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/101127/whats-the-workflow-to-bulk-delete-e-mails-from-within-gmail), possibly dependent upon the browser.

*In particular, this is about the checkmark to apply to all e-mail which match the search criteria of the filter.*

Comment: there's an API:  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java to force a bulk delete.  Probably would peg the CPU for quite a while, however.